# Edit-based distance(matching) with custom character substitution distance

Tags: python, r, edit-distance

I want to match a string with another string from OCR(Optical Character Recognition).

Usually, OCR-read text are imperfect. In my case, 5's are misrecognized as S and so on.

So I am wondering if there's a way to calucate a edit-distance with custom distance.

For example, if I want to calculate a distance from `5S00AS` to `SSOODS`,

I would want to make a substitution distance for `A` to `D` large and `5` to `S` small so that `distance('5S00AS', 'SSOOAS')` is much smaller than `distance('5S00AS', 'PDDDDA')`.

I think soundex is in the similar vein except that similar sounds have smaller distance. We should have smaller distance for simliar looking spellings.

I wonder if there is already a function or package for doing this type of distance calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Levenshtein distance with a custom scores. See the more general [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman–Wunsch_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm)

The nltk lib levenshein implementation doesn't support using custom scores, but in needleman-wunsch implemenations you can usually specify this (it's easy to modify the algorithm to use a matrix of custom distances).